# Why Principal is null after successful auth in Spring REST app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm implementing an authentication in my Spring rest app right now, so I send a request from a Electron.js app and Spring handles everything.

So right now if I sign in via browser it saves my object and returns Principal successfully. But if I sign in and try to send a request to return that Principal via Electron.js app, it throws NullException.

```java
@GetMapping("/user")
public String user(Principal principal)
{
    return principal.getName(); // null via rest app (electron app), not null via browser (authenticated)
}

@GetMapping("/loginRequest") // this is method that requires user's credentials
public UserModel login(Principal principal)
{
   return userDAO.findByUsername(principal.getName()); // signs in on both (browser and rest app), returns json object
}
```

Configuration looks this way:

```java
    @Autowired
    private MongoUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/loginRequest").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception
    {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Request from Electron.js

```js
axios(API + 'loginRequest', {
          method: 'GET',
          auth: {
            username: this.username, // Both username & pass are taken from fields
            password: this.password
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.userObject = response.data;
        }).catch(err => this.showError('Username or password is invalid', 2));
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And the "/user" request ?

Comment: This looks like your `loginRequest` *is* the controller that's supposed to be handling the login, not a controller that's supposed run after the login process has already completed. I very strongly recommend not reimplementing logic (such as login handling) that's already available out of the box with Spring Security; it's extra work and more likely to have bugs.

Comment: @FrancescRecio yeah I use this request obviously, returns null

Comment: @chrylis this method handles the login, after what it returns a user object, but it should keep the principal, but it doesn't do so at the rest app

Comment: In a spring basic authentication, the user is not kept, must be sent in every request

Comment: @FrancescRecio Thanks. What should be implemented in order to keep it? Token auth I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two options:

**First option:**

Would be to use the remember me that provides you spring, with JSESSIONID cookie management, here I leave you a tutorial where it is explained very well, and is simple:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-remember-me

**Second option:**

Use OAuth2 as you say in the comment, but is a little more expensive to implement, requires more dependencies, have a third party validate tokens and the configuration is longer.

Here is a guide:

https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular